# How to unsubscribe from a Firestore stream using the Vue onInvalidate callback?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Vue 3 to create a Firebase composable that subscribes to an `onSnapshot()` stream.

And I am trying to unsunscribe from that stream by calling the returned `unsubscribe()` function inside `watchEffect` and `onInvalidate`. [Here are the Vue docs that explain those particular functions](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-computed-watchers.html#side-effect-invalidation).

Using a `console.log()` I can confirm my `watchEffect` is firing.

But I cannot trigger my second `console.log()` that exists inside `onInvalidate`, and therefore I'm not sure if the `unsubscribe()` function is ever called.

In the code below, why doesn't my `console.log("unsubscribe fired");` ever fire?

How else can I be sure I am unsubscribed from the Firestore stream? Is there a log of this inside the Firebase dashboard or something similar?

Here is the Vue Firestore composable (it is written in TypeScript):

```
import { ref, reactive, watchEffect } from "vue";
import { projectFirestore } from "@/firebase/config";
import {
  query,
  orderBy,
  onSnapshot,
  DocumentData,
  collection,
} from "firebase/firestore";

const useCollection: any = (col: any) => {
  const documents = reactive<Record<string, unknown>[]>([]);
  const error = ref<string | null>(null);
  // references
  const collectionReference = collection(projectFirestore, col);
  const collectionOrdered = query(
    collectionReference,
    orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
  );
  // updates
  const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
    collectionOrdered,
    (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc: DocumentData) => {
        documents.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
      });
      error.value = null;
      console.log(documents);
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log(err.message);
      documents.splice(0);
      error.value = err.message;
    }
  );
  watchEffect((onInvalidate) => {
    console.log("watchEffect fired"); //This fires
    onInvalidate(() => {
      unsubscribe();
      console.log("unsubscribe fired"); //This does not fire
    });
  });
  return { documents, error };
};

export default useCollection;
```

Comment: Hi, is the issue resolved?

Comment: I can't remember how, but I figured out it was being called but just not logged to the console for some reason. But I forget the answer now sorry! Will come back and add it as an answer if I do ever remember what it was.

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't any reactive object in your callback of watchEffect

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).